# How Do We Point androidTest to a Peer Eclipse-Style Project?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am helping out the Guardian Project on [NetCipher](https://github.com/guardianproject/NetCipher). For legacy reasons, they want to keep their existing project structure, which was based on Eclipse. However, rather than having the tests in a `tests/` subdirectory of the library, they went with a peer project model. So, off of the repo root, `libnetcipher/` is the library and `netciphertest/` are the instrumentation tests.

The instrumentation tests were never set up for Gradle builds, unlike `libnetcipher/` itself. So, I am adding stuff to the `libnetcipher/build.gradle` file to have it point its `androidTest` sourceset to the `netciphertest/` directory, rather than its normal location.

This works:

```
    androidTest {
        manifest.srcFile '../netciphertest/AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['../netciphertest/src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['../netciphertest/src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['../netciphertest/src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['../netciphertest/src']
        res.srcDirs = ['../netciphertest/res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['../netciphertest/assets']
    }
```

However, the duplicate `../netciphertest` bits are icky. I could define that as a constant to minimize the duplication, of course. I'm trying to figure out if there's a better approach to the whole problem.

For example, this doesn't work:

```
    androidTest.setRoot('../netciphertest')

    androidTest {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }
```

I thought that perhaps the `srcDirs` and `srcFile` stuff might be interpreted relative to the `setRoot()` value, but they seem to be interpreted relative to the project's own root.

Is there a more elegant solution than what I have working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading over the Gradle documentation, I couldn't find anything about relative vs absolute paths for the `srcDirs`, but it seems that if you just give `src` that it will assume `./src` regardless of the root that was set. Maybe this could be a Gradle feature request or might work as expected in later versions of Gradle? Not sure, didn't look into it.

That being said, assuming you don't need `aidl`, `renderscripts`, or `resources` (since they don't appear used in the project), then is this less "icky"?

```
androidTest {
    setRoot '../netciphertest'
    java.srcDirs = ['../netciphertest/src']
}
```

All the others will be automatically be setup like this if you don't override them and just set the root.

```
androidTest.manifest.srcFile = /NetCipher/netciphertest/AndroidManifest.xml
androidTest.res.srcDirs = [/NetCipher/netciphertest/res]
androidTest.assets.srcDirs = [/NetCipher/netciphertest/assets]

// Override these, if you wish
androidTest.resources.srcDirs = [/NetCipher/netciphertest/resources]
androidTest.aidl.srcDirs = [/NetCipher/netciphertest/aidl]
androidTest.renderscript.srcDirs = [/NetCipher/netciphertest/rs]
```

You can print out the paths within Gradle and play around with it more if you like by including this section within the `sourceSets` block.

```
println "androidTest.manifest.srcFile = ${androidTest.manifest.srcFile}"
println "androidTest.java.srcDirs = ${androidTest.java.srcDirs}"
println "androidTest.resources.srcDirs = ${androidTest.resources.srcDirs}"
println "androidTest.aidl.srcDirs = ${androidTest.aidl.srcDirs}"
println "androidTest.renderscript.srcDirs = ${androidTest.renderscript.srcDirs}"
println "androidTest.res.srcDirs = ${androidTest.res.srcDirs}"
println "androidTest.assets.srcDirs = ${androidTest.assets.srcDirs}"
```

Comment: "then is this less "icky"?" -- somewhat. I was seeking a more general-purpose answer, though. While that would help my specific scenario, enough to drive the "ick" down to reasonable levels, I was hoping that there was a better solution that didn't make those sorts of simplifying assumptions. I'll probably do this cleanup if no other better option arises. Thanks!

Comment: I was reading about [injection](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec:injected_configuration) also, so maybe putting a build.gradle into the `netciphertest` folder could work, then "injecting" that sourceSet into the other module.

Comment: @CommonsWare I saw your pull request was accepted on Github. Did you end up finding a better approach?

Comment: The pull request had the code from my question -- it just took a while to get the request merged. I'll eventually revisit it based on our discussion here.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still confused by `setRoot` method, just calling it at the end of your sourceSet block.

This is how this method implements.

```
override fun setRoot(path: String): AndroidSourceSet {
    return initRoot(path)
}

private fun initRoot(path: String): AndroidSourceSet {
    javaSource.setSrcDirs(listOf("$path/java"))
    javaResources.setSrcDirs(listOf("$path/resources"))
    res.setSrcDirs(listOf("$path/${SdkConstants.FD_RES}"))
    assets.setSrcDirs(listOf("$path/${SdkConstants.FD_ASSETS}"))
    manifest.srcFile("$path/${SdkConstants.FN_ANDROID_MANIFEST_XML}")
    aidl.setSrcDirs(listOf("$path/aidl"))
    renderscript.setSrcDirs(listOf("$path/rs"))
    jni.setSrcDirs(listOf("$path/jni"))
    jniLibs.setSrcDirs(listOf("$path/jniLibs"))
    shaders.setSrcDirs(listOf("$path/shaders"))
    return this
}
```

The document is too bad.